# Unable to connect to Odata source v4 and v2 in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, odata, etl, ssis-2017

**Objective**:
Connect Odata Source in SSIS to [Medicare data](https://data.medicare.gov/Nursing-Home-Compare/Provider-Info/4pq5-n9py/data)

When tried [Odata v4 endpoint](https://data.medicare.gov/api/odata/v4/4pq5-n9py):

- Get "Test connection Failed" when creating Connection Manager.

[image: screenshot]

- Confirmed endpoint works in Tableau desktop connection

When tried [Odata v2 endpoint](https://data.medicare.gov/OData.svc/4pq5-n9py):

- Get connection successful when creating Connection Manager

[image: screenshot]

- "unable to load collection" with Odata Source Editor

[image: screenshot]

Using SSIS Visual Studio 2017 v 15.5.5

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update 1

Just enter the following URL in the ODATA connection manager

```
https://data.medicare.gov/OData.svc
```

And it will work perfectly.

[image]

To get the dataset you are looking for just Select to use Resource Path instead of collection, and write `4pq5-n9py` as `Resource Path`

[image]

[image]

---

## Initial Answer

First of all, this is the link of v4

```
https://data.medicare.gov/api/odata/v4/4pq5-n9py
```

And if you access it you will see that there is an error retrieving data from this link *(just copy and paste this link into your browser)*

[image]

And using v2 you have to work with this link

```
https://data.medicare.gov/OData.svc/4pq5-n9py
```

If you open it using your browser, you will see that it returns data, but it will take a long time to finish loading it.

After trying to open the data from browser, try again to do this using ODATA Source, it will works, but it will take a lot of time.

The issue may be caused due to a Timeout expiration, or due to the message maximum size.

Try changing the corresponding values in the ODATA connection manager

[image]

Comment: Tried and still not able to connect. What are you using for your other settings? I tried both Window Authentication and Basic Authentication as well as Collection and Resource Path

Comment: @VinhTon I found it, just enter `https://data.medicare.gov/OData.svc` as a datasource on the ODATA connection manager, Check my answer update

Comment: thanks for the screenshots, I noticed my doesn't have protocal v3. I'm going to try updating the drivers, otherwise everything else looks the same

Comment: Thanks @Hadi !! Not sure if it was the drivers but it definitely was the path. I was including the resource rather than using only url: https://data.medicare.gov/OData.svc